# How to show img on modal based on element index?

Tags: javascript

I have a gallery of image, it looks like this:
[image]

When I click on any of these images a popup shows up with an img, I'd like to make the popup dynamic, meaning that the img of the popup should be based on the element that was clicked.

This is the html structure:

```
<div class="gallery">
      <img src="img/hg-1.jpg" alt="Interior view" class="gallery__img">
      <img src="img/hg-2.jpg" alt="Interior view" class="gallery__img">
      <img src="img/hg-3.jpg" alt="Interior view" class="gallery__img">
      <img src="img/hg-4.jpg" alt="Interior view" class="gallery__img">
      <img src="img/hg-5.jpg" alt="Interior view" class="gallery__img">
      <img src="img/hg-6.jpg" alt="Interior view" class="gallery__img">
      <img src="img/hg-7.jpg" alt="Interior view" class="gallery__img">
      <img src="img/hg-8.jpg" alt="Interior view" class="gallery__img">
      <img src="img/hg-9.jpg" alt="Interior view" class="gallery__img">
      <img src="img/hg-10.jpg" alt="Interior view" class="gallery__img">
      <img src="img/hg-11.jpg" alt="Interior view" class="gallery__img">
      <img src="img/hg-12.jpg" alt="Interior view" class="gallery__img">
    </div>
```

The Js code:

```
// Overlay template
const overlay = el => `
<div class="overlay">
  <button class="overlay__close-icon" id="closeOverlay">&times;</button>
  <img src="img/prev.png" alt="Previous button" class="overlay__btn">
  <img src="img/hg-1.jpg" alt="Interior view" class="overlay__img">
  <img src="img/next.png" alt="Next button" class="overlay__btn">
</div>`;

// Inject template to html structure
document.querySelector('#main').insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', overlay);

const addClickEvent = () => {
  document.querySelector('.overlay').classList.add('showOverlay')
  document.querySelector('body').style.overflow = 'hidden'
};


let query = document.querySelector('.gallery');
let images = 'gallery__img';
if (!query) {
  query = document.querySelector('.section-gallery');
  images = 'section-' + images;
}

// Nodelist elements
const imageElems = document.querySelectorAll("." + images);

// Convert nodelist into array
let imgArr = [...imageElems];

// Open overlay
query.addEventListener('click', () => {
  addClickEvent(imageElems)

  // I want to make this piece of code dynamic, 
  // right now it's just returning the element of index 2.
  document.querySelector('.overlay__img').src = imgArr[2].src;
});

// Close overlay
document.querySelector('#closeOverlay').addEventListener('click', () => {
  document.querySelector('.overlay').classList.remove('showOverlay');
  document.querySelector('body').style.overflow = 'auto'
});
```

I'm trying to change the src of the popup based on the index of the element in the array, but I am having problems. I know how to do this with Jquery, but I just want to use plain JS with this project. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Find the clicked element's index in its container from the `event` argument, and then you can reference the `imgArr` at that index:

```
query.addEventListener('click', (event) => {
  const { target } = event;
  // If the click was in the container but not on any of the images, return:
  if (!target.matches('.gallery__img')) return;
  addClickEvent(imageElems); // ???
  const index =  Array.prototype.indexOf.call(query.children, target);
  document.querySelector('.overlay__img').src = imgArr[index].src;
});
```

(Not sure what you're doing with the `addClickEvent(imageElems);` line - `addClickEvent` doesn't accept any arguments in your code, maybe change to `addClickEvent();`)

Comment: Hey, thanks for the quick reply, this code works. But would you minda explaining this piece of code here `const { target } = event;` Why the brackets? Your original code works perfectly btw, you edited your answer.

Comment: That's destructuring - `const { target } = event` is the same as `var target = event.target`. Less syntax noise.

Comment: The `addClickEvent();` function is not needed, It was just that originally I coded everything in a less efficient way and I needed that function to show the overlay.